# Map ObsidianExtractNote in neovim

Tags: neovim, obsidian

I'm trying to map `<leader>ox` to call ObsidianExtractNote from [obsidian.nvim](https://github.com/epwalsh/obsidian.nvim) plugin

```
vim.keymap.set('x', '<leader>ox', '<cmd>ObsidianExtractNote<cr>')
```

When I just call `:ObsidianExtractNote` in command mode it prompts to name a new note and works just fine.

But pressing `<leader>ox` fails with an error:

```
attempt to index local 'new_id'
```

I also tried to map this command with a constant name to avoid the prompt:

```
vim.keymap.set('x', '<leader>ox', '<cmd>ObsidianExtractNote note_name<cr>')
```

But this time the new error occurred:

```
Invalid 'start_col': out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution.

I thought that `<cmd>` and `:` are equals but they are not.
`<cmd>` doesn't change mode instead of `:`.

After changing mapping to `vim.keymap.set('x', '<leader>ox', ':ObsidianExtractNote<cr>')` all errors are gone.